# An increasing sequence whose terms contain only odd digits

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Consider the ***increasing*** sequence: $13579, 13597, \dots,199153773,\dots$, where every term contains all (and only) the digits $1,3,5,7,9$ (every digit must appear ***at least once*** in every term, so repetition is allowed).

What is the $1992^\text{nd}$ term in the sequence?

What is the order (the term number) of $199153773$?

---

I am not sure how to start.

I am just thinking that the $1992^\text{nd}$ contains $\left \lfloor \frac{1992}{5!} \right \rfloor = \left \lfloor \frac{1992}{120} \right \rfloor =  \left \lfloor 16.6 \right \rfloor = 16$ digits.

I am not sure. And I am not asking for the answer, I am just asking for help/hints, then I will edit my post to show you my attempt, if right or wrong.

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:**

I give up. Barry Cipra and  Wolfgang Kais commented (really appreciated).

I just confused about counting the $6$-digit numbers.

Comment: I think it might have to do with the number of digits along with the number of transpositions required to make the digits of the number ordered.

Comment: Not sure the rules are clear.  Can the terms in the sequence contain other digits?  Is, say, $135792$ on the list?

Comment: @lulu the title says that the terms contain only odd digits.

Comment: Hint: Start by carefully counting the number of six-digit numbers there are of the kind you are allowing.

Comment: @lulu (Only) odd digits $1,3,5,7,9$. (All) odd digits $1,3,5,7,9$. (Repetition) is allowed. Is it clear now dear?

Comment: Yes, though the assumptions should appear in the problem statement, not just in the title.  I think the hint from @BarryCipra  is a strong one.  Not sure where your estimate is coming from..there are a lot of six digit strings of your form.  There are already $\binom 62\times 4!=360$ which have two $1's$

Comment: The sequence contains $5!=120$ numbers with just $5$ digits, $\binom{5}{1}6!/2! = 1800$ numbers with exactly $6$ digits and $\binom{5}{2}7!/(2!)^2 + \binom{5}{1}7!/3! = 16800$ numbers with exactly 7 digits. Since $120+1800 < 1992 < 120+1800+16800$, the $1992^\text{nd}$ term has $7$ digits.

Comment: Is this a problem from pure combinatorics or you are supposed to write some computer code to provide the answers?

Answer (score 1):

$1992^{nd}$ term is 1137597.

Index of term 199153773 is 306430.

```
def isValidNumList(numList):
    for x in [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]:
        if not x in numList:
            return False
    return True

def nextNumList(numList):
    numList.reverse()
    valid = False
    while not valid:
        overflow = 1
        for i in range(0, len(numList)):
            if overflow == 0:
                break;
            if numList[i] == 9:
                numList[i] = 1
            else:
                numList[i] += 2
                overflow = 0
        if overflow > 0:
            numList.append(1)
        valid = isValidNumList(numList)
    numList.reverse()

def getNumber(numList):
    res = 0
    for digit in numList:
        res *= 10
        res += digit
    return res

def findNumber(index):
    n = 1
    numList = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
    while n != index:
        nextNumList(numList)
        n += 1
    return getNumber(numList)

def findIndex(number):
    n = 1
    numList = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
    while getNumber(numList) != number:
        nextNumList(numList)
        n += 1
    return n

# prints 1137597
print(findNumber(1992))

# prints 306430
print(findIndex(199153773))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. You answer can be used to verify the purely mathematical way. If you know how, please share. Thanks. +1